# Bootstrap multi-level drop down not working

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a PHP website. And for some reasons, I need to add multiple level dropdown in my navigation bar. I tried the bootstrap class="**dropdown-submenu**" but I don't know why it has not worked.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <?php 
        $alllinks = mysql_query("SELECT `cid`, `cname`  FROM `services` WHERE `parentid`=0");
        while($reslink = mysql_fetch_assoc($alllinks)){ ?>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo MYWEBSITE;?>services/<?php echo to_prety_url($reslink['cname']).'-'.$reslink['cid'];?>.html">
             <?php echo $reslink['cname'];?>
             </a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                     <a href="<?php echo MYWEBSITE;?>servicedetail/<?php echo to_prety_url($rowsb['cname']).'-'.$rowsb['cid'];?>.html">
                         <?php echo $rowsb['cname'];?> 
                     </a> 
                  </li><br>
             </ul>
        </li><br>
        <?php } ?>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout your code You haven't enclosed MYWEBSITE in inverted comma's
you have written.

```
<?php echo MYWEBSITE;?>
```

whereas you should write

```
<?php echo "MYWEBSITE";?>
```

and You are using the old and Deprecated mysql connector it is higly recommended that you switch to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: ThanX @reevkandari I will switch to mysqli

Comment: Go For PDO. mysqli will only work my mysql, whereas PDO can be used with any database of your choice. very useful in the long run.

Comment: Thanx for your honest advice :-) I will switch to PDO